# removing an object using lists and other data structure

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, stack, queue

I'm trying to remove all objects with the colour orange from my program which are in the list stack and queue, currently having difficulty on how to progress from my code and just need to get an idea of how to start it properly. I've made an attempt but it just seems to keep creating more shapes. any help would be great thanks !

```
from tkinter import *
import random
root = Tk()
from Stack import Stack
from my_queue import *

class Recta:

  def __init__(self, height=60, width=80 ,colours= []):
    self.height = height
    self.width = width
    self.canvas = Canvas(root)
    self.canvas.pack()
    self.colours = ["red", "orange"]
    self.rects = []
    self.stack = Stack()
    self.queue = Queue()


  def randomCircle(self):
    w = random.randrange(300)
    h = random.randrange(200)
    self.stack.push(self.canvas.create_oval(0,0,w,h,fill= random.choice(self.colours)))


  def randomRects(self):
    w = random.randrange(300)
    h = random.randrange(200)
    self.rects.append(self.canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, w, h, fill= random.choice(self.colours)))

   def random_arc(self):
    x1 = random.randrange(300)
    y1 = random.randrange(200)
    x2 = random.randrange(300)
    y2 = random.randrange(200)
    e = random.randrange(90) 
    s = 45 + ( 90 -e)/2
    self.queue.enqueue(self.canvas.create_arc( x1, y1, x2, y2 ,start=s,extent=e,fill= random.choice(self.colours)))

 def remove_all_orange_shapes(self):
    if self.randomRects() == "orange":
        self.canvas.delete(self.rects.pop())
    elif self.randomCircle() == "orange":
        self.canvas.delete(self.stack.pop())
    elif self.random_arc() == "orange":
        self.canvas.delete(self.queue.dequeue())




tes = Recta()
tes= Stack()
tes = Queue()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you clarify where in your code you are trying to remove the orange objects?

Comment: You have the comparison `if self.randomRects() == "orange":` but `self.randomRects()` has no `return` statement, so it returns `None`, not a string.  `remove_circle()` and `remove_arc()` are not shown.

Comment: those shouldn't be remove_circle it should be randomCircle an random_arc sorry -.- ill edit code again

Comment: do i return self.canvas.delete(self.rects.pop())

Comment: My previous comment applies:  those methods don't have a return statement so they return `None`.

Comment: What does your design say they should return?

Comment: so at the moment I have a bunch of shapes and my design is returning all of them when I click a button. It makes all the shapes pop up at once, instead of removing just the set shapes I want

Comment: they should return shapes that have been removed by a press of a button. But i first need to create the function which will remove all orange coloured shapes

Comment: You need to add something the the class that will give the colour of the shape.  Right now you don't appear to have anything there, and your methods don't return anything.

Comment: the colours are all stored in the list right now. Thats why when I return it, it gives me different colours of different shapes